# Shorthand array doesn't work on server

Tags: php, arrays, hosting

I'm hosting a standard website from `http://www.versio.nl/` and I'm always getting the error `Parse: syntax error, unexpected '['`. I would have to change all the `[]` array notifications with `array()`. But is there a possiblity that I can change a setting or so? Or could it be they still work with an old version of PHP? (Looks strange to me)

Comment: Short array syntax has been added from PHP 5.4.0 .. What is your PHP Version ?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.27, damn that sucks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only php 5.4.x and up works with the new shorthand array syntax,
if your server version is lower then 5.4 then there's no way to make it work, you'll need to change the syntax to the old syntax.

you could try to see the version using

```
echo phpinfo();
```

Comment: My version is 5.6.30 but these shortcuts do not work either.